Работа strcmp. Она будто меняет значение
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <math.h>
//#include <netinet/in.h>
//#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 8000
#define MAX_REQUEST 8
#define MAX_USERS 100
#define MAX_HTML_COUNTER 10
#define MAX_LENGTH 50
#define MAX_ROOMS 8
#define MAX_USERS_IN_ROOM 8

typedef struct{
    //Start string
    char Method[20];
    char URL[MAX_LENGTH];
    char Protocol[10];
    //Heading
    char Host[MAX_LENGTH];
    char Date [MAX_LENGTH];
    char Last_Modified[MAX_LENGTH];
    char Content_Type[MAX_LENGTH];
    char Content_Language [MAX_LENGTH];
    char Content_Length [MAX_LENGTH];
    char Connection[MAX_LENGTH];
    char Cach_Control[MAX_LENGTH];
    char Upgrade_Insecure_Requests[MAX_LENGTH];
    char Origin[MAX_LENGTH];
    char User_Agent[200];
    char Accept[200];
    char Referer[MAX_LENGTH];
    char Accept_Encoding[MAX_LENGTH];
    char Accept_Language[MAX_LENGTH];
}HTTP_Context;

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    char s[correct_size("D:\\p\\a\\buffer.txt")];//возвращает требуемый объем для файла
    send_html("D:\\p\\a\\buffer.txt", s);//вставляет в "с" содержимое файла
    HTTP_Context HTTP_ex;
    create_http_struct(s, &HTTP_ex);// Подставляет соответствующие HTTP значения 
    printf("Method=%s\nURL=%s\nProtocol=%s\n", HTTP_ex.Method, HTTP_ex. URL, 
    HTTP_ex.Protocol);
    if(strcmp(HTTP_ex.Protocol, "HTTP/1.1\0")!=0){
        printf("%s != %s\n", HTTP_ex.Protocol, "HTTP/1.1\0");
    }
    return 0;
}

После работы функции strcmp значение HTTP_ex.Protocol меняется и оно ничего не выводит.
Моя функция (create_http_struct) вставляет символ конца строки в конце каждого аргумента
Вывод программы:
Method=GET
URL=/
Protocol=HTTP/1.1
!=HTTP/1.1\0

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить. 10 раз себе голову сломал, пока думал в каком месте сглупил.

Из соображений краткости не стал писать сюда мою функцию, но она действительно работает, что доказывает строка, которая шла перед if

Из соображений краткости не стал писать сюда мой ответ, но он действительно помогает.

Мой внутренний телепат нашёптывает мне \r но из соображений краткости не стал пояснять мне что это значит

Кхм... убрал вообще конструкцию if...
        `printf("%s != %s\n", HTTP_ex.Protocol, "HTTP/1.1\0");`
 `printf("%s\n", HTTP_ex.Protocol);`

Первая ничего не выводит, а вторая корректно выполняет задачу...
Так что да, дело не функции strcmp. А в кривых ручках. Знать бы как именно работает это.

Мой внутренний телепат продолжает настойчиво нашёптывать printf("ABCD\rEF\n");

АААА, в конце первой строки HTTP стоит '\r'.... Да, я дурак, спасибо огромное)

Первая строка HTTP-заголовка такова:
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\r\n

Я не учел того, что в конце стоит возврат каретки. И в HTTP_ex.Protocol вошло значение вместе с возвратом каретки.
Спасибо огромное комментариям, которые мне на это намекнули.
